# Nginx: парный балансировщик

Tags: linux, nginx

На данный момент есть nginx-балансировщик (Centos 7, виртуалка с белым адресом) проксирующий на большое количество бэкенд-серверов с Апачем запросы. Необходимо реализовать отказоустойчивый кластер из двух балансировщиков на nginx. Отказоустойчивость пробно реализована с помощью виртуального ip-адреса (используется keepalived). Подскажите, где/что можно почитать на тему парного nginx-балансировщика: все приходящие на них запросы на одном виртуальном ip-адресе равномерно распределялись между ними двумя, но при отказе одного из них оставшийся забирает всё на себя.

На данный момент получается, что есть два одинаковых балансировщика и польза второго только в подстраховке. В моменты полноценной работы основного (мастера), второй (бэкап) бесполезно простаивает.

Сейчас реализовано так:
[image]

Нужно реализовать так:

[image]

Есть ли возможность реализовать подобный кластер через **linux virtual server** (ipvsadm, например)?

Comment: keepalived должен отключить сломанный nginx

Comment: Верно, это уже реализовано. А как реализовать равномерное распределение нагрузки между этими двумя балансерами?

Comment: Если чуть позднее никто не оставит подробное описание, то я попробую расписать как это делается в некоторых из крупных компаний (пишу, что попробую, т.к. я не сисадмин и какие-то детали, вероятно, могу упустить), т.к. Round-Robin DNS используется, скорее, для подстраховки (и то далеко не всеми, например, в рамках доменного имени "online.sberbank.ru" таковые не используются). Просто, там имеется, как минимум, несколько вариантов, основанных на нескольких слоях балансировщиков, реализованных на разных уровнях модели OSI (L7/L4/L3), кроющихся за Cluster IP за счет одинакового BGP веса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я понимаю, это фронт... А для фронта можно применить [RoundRobin DNS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round_robin_DNS) Cобственно именно его и используют всякие яндексы и гуглы.

> Round robin DNS — один из методов распределения нагрузки, или отказоустойчивости за счёт избыточности количества серверов, с помощью управления ответами DNS-сервера в соответствии с некой статистической моделью. Обычно применяется к таким интернет-протоколам, как веб-серверы, FTP-серверы.
>   В простейшем случае Round robin DNS работает, отвечая на запросы не только одним IP-адресом, а списком из нескольких адресов серверов, предоставляющих идентичный сервис. Порядок, в котором возвращаются IP-адреса из списка, основан на алгоритме round-robin. С каждым ответом последовательность ip-адресов меняется. Как правило, простые клиенты пытаются устанавливать соединения с первым адресом из списка, таким образом разным клиентам будут выданы адреса разных серверов, что распределит общую нагрузку между серверами.

Проще говоря, у вас в конфигурации DNS сервера должно быть 2 A записи указывающие на разные IP ваших серверов. Вот как например это у Яндекса.
[image: RRDNS]

Comment: То есть, если я правльно понял, для начала нужно создать домен для балансироващиков? Доменную зону делегировать на DNS-сервера нашей организации и там прописать А-записи? Сейчас балансировщик просто на белом адресе без какого-либо домена.

Comment: Даже не домен, а прописать A записи в домене вашей организации в конфигурацию DNS. У вас только один внешний IP или есть возможность добавить ещё один, для второго хоста? Если да, то конфигурация будет такая. Допустим у вас домен example.com, вы хотите что-б балансировщики были доступны по адресу www.example.com, тогда записи будут такие:
`www                             A       1.22.333.44`

`www                             A       1.22.333.45`
При этом не важно сколько за доменным именем будет скрываться IP адресов. У яндекса их 4, у гугла 6, например